# Counting row from a query that includes an EXCEPT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, coalesce

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         SREF, DELIVERYDATE, DATEIDENTIFIED, DCID, SUPN, PONUMBER,
     FROM 
         BNHEAD 
     WHERE 
         (SUPP = 'Sanchez') AND (STAT = '2')

     EXCEPT

     SELECT 
         SREF, DELIVERYDATE, DATEIDENTIFIED, DCID, SUPN, PONUMBER,
     FROM 
         BNHEAD 
     WHERE 
         (SUPP = 'sanchez') 
         AND (STAT = '2') 
         AND ((STI = 'Yes') AND (RESN = 'third party')) 
          OR (FORWARDEDTO = 'STI')) t1
ORDER BY 
    DeliveryDate DESC
```

How do I get the row count only from this query and if it is zero return 0 ? I think it might need to involve coalesce but I'm unsure how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just use `select count(*)` in the outer query:

```
select count(*)
from (select sref . . .
      . . .
     ) t
```

`select count(*)` always returns one row (when there is no `group by`).  It will return `0` if there are no rows in the subquery.